# Wildfly EJB lookup works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: windows, ejb, jndi, wildfly, remote-access

I am struggling with the current wildfly 9.0.2 and the JNDI lookup.
I desperatly try to run the 'ejb-remote' example from the wildfly-quickstarts and am seeking for help.

When running wildfly on Linux (Suse Enterprise 11), the example works fine with a Linux client and and a Windows (Windows 7) client.
When running wildfly on Windows, the example only works fine with the Linux client.
Trying to run the example with a Windows client, when starting the client locally as well as from another machine (though still in the same subnet), results in the following exception:

```
Apr 15, 2016 10:34:02 AM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection handleException
ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 2f58a725 to /192.168.XXX.XXX:8080
Apr 15, 2016 10:34:02 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 192.168.XXX.XXX:8080
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 2f58a725 to /192.168.XXX.XXX:8080
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:92)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:158)
```

...

The wildfly (standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0) and the example are started out of the box.
I have only added application users (add-user.bat) and thus have added (remote.connection.default.username=test, remote.connection.default.password=test) to the 'jboss-ejb-client.properties'.
I also tried to indicate the servers IP address in different ways (localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.XXX.XXX). No success.

Does anyone have another idea or a hint where to look for the problem (wildfly itself, firewall, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on a windows machine and it turned out that there was an issue with the antivirus(Kaspersky in my case), which was causing the issue.

You can disable the antivirus and try, if the connection is successful, you will have to fine tune the antivirus policies.

Comment: is there any other workaround rather than stopping antivirus